# Bagplot implementation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, statistics, gps, gis

I'm trying to approximate GPS coordinates from n different locations.

I read here that using a bagplot would be a good idea:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/161838/approximating-gps-coordinates-for-a-point-from-n-expected-locations

I'm trying to implement this in Swift and can't seem to figure out an easy way to do so.